# redirect old pages by .htaccess

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess

I want to redirect pages from **sitename/sitename/pagename.html** and **sitemap/sitename/**  to

```
sitemap/sitename/pagename
```

how I can do that by using `.htaccess` file

I tried this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule . /sitename/index.php [L]
RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.html$ sitename/$1
</IfModule>
```

and I tried also to add

```
 Redirect 301 sitename/sitename/
```

but it is not working
but I think both not working because it still gives me an error when I open `www.sitename.com/pagename.html`

Comment: In trying to "exemplify" the code you've actually changed its meaning and made it invalid!?

Answer (score 0):

`%postname%` is not a [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rewrite tag. You are going to have to write out the path. `mod_rewrite` operates before WordPress, or PHP, gets involved. You don't have access to any of that functionality.

If your "contact" page-- the page named "contact"-- has ID 213 you shouldn't have to do anything to redirect, though. This will happen when you enable pretty permalinks.

You can also redirect using WordPress functionality by doing something like:

```
function redirect_213() {
  if (is_page(213)) {
    wp_safe_redirect(wp_safe_redirect(home_url('/contact')));
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect','redirect_213');
```

This will probably perform slightly less efficiently than the `.htaccess` but you may not notice.

Comment: thanks for reply but i want to do that not only for this page for all the other pages so i there is a way to do this for all pages -- i mean for all html pages

Comment: That is very different from what you asked in your question. Please edit you question so that it actually asks what you want to ask!